# How to make Dart files break one line per parameter in VsCode?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, ide, editor

I am learning Flutter/Dart, and in the video series I am following, there is only one parameter per line, as follows:

```
body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, 
          children: [
            Text('Counter ${counter}'),
            CustomSwitch(),
          ]),
      )
```

but in my editor, the line won't break per parameter.

Since I am using [Dart Recommended Settings](https://dartcode.org/docs/recommended-settings/), I thought it would be the same here in my editor, but what happens is the following:

```
body: Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        height: double.infinity,
        child: Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
          Text('Counter ${counter}'),
          CustomSwitch(),
        ]),
```

See how the 'child' property has both `mainAxisAliment` and `children` in the same line?

How do I setup my settings, so that doesn't happen, and one parameter is shown per line?

I thought I could just reduce the line width (currently 80, as suggested), but that wouldn't break exactly one parameter per line.

Comment: you can another coma , it will format the code.  `], ),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding coma`,`whenever possible will provide your desire result. In your case, you can add another coma after `],`. This will format the code.

```
 CustomSwitch(),
    ],
  ),
```

Comment: any ideas on how to add those , by default?

Comment: idk, I just keep adding coma while writing the code & I usually use `save on format` Also,  `dart format .` command is amazing.

Comment: There's a lint you can turn on that shows you where you're missing commas, and even has a quickfix if you have quickfix-on-save.  I forget the name, but my recommended "very good analysis" package has it enabled.